# Show that the points are collinear

Tags: 3d

Show that the points $$\mathbf a-2\mathbf b+3\mathbf c ,\quad 2\mathbf a+3\mathbf b-4\mathbf c ,\quad-7\mathbf b+10\mathbf c$$ are collinear. Where $\mathbf a ,\mathbf b,\mathbf c$ are vectors .

I thought as

Let the points be $k ,l ,m$ then

$(k\times l)\cdot m=0$

Can I prove it like this

Comment: No, this only shows that they lie on a plane.  What you've calculated is the triple product, which measures the volume of a parallelepiped formed by the three vectors.  There are more ways to have zero volume than to have all the points collinear.

Comment: Take two of the points and construct the line through those two. Then show that the third point also lies on that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The simplest way*:

If $A,B,C$ are collinear, then $AB$ and $AC$ are proportional.

**In your case**, $$(-1,10,7)=\lambda(1,-10,-7).$$

Obviously, yes they are collinear.

Comment: Can you explain it more

Comment: @koolman We have $\overrightarrow{AB} =(-1, 10, 7) $ and $\overrightarrow{AC} =(1, -10, -7) $. We can see that they are scalar multiples of each other so $A,B,C $ are collinear.

Answer (score 1):

Let's denote the three points by $\mathbf{k}$, $\mathbf{l}$, $\mathbf{m}$, as you suggested. Then let $\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{l} - \mathbf{k}$, and $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{k} - \mathbf{m}$. Then the three points $\mathbf{k}$, $\mathbf{l}$, $\mathbf{m}$ are collinear if and only if $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are parallel. To show that they are parallel, you can check that $\mathbf{u} \times  \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$, or you can show that $\mathbf{u}$ is a scalar multiple of $\mathbf{v}$.

A couple of people have suggested that $\mathbf{k}$, $\mathbf{l}$, $\mathbf{m}$ are collinear if and only if $(\mathbf{k} \times \mathbf{l}) \cdot \mathbf{m} = 0$. This is not correct. The triple product (or the corresponding determinant) will be zero iff the position vectors of the three points are **coplanar**. Collinear implies coplanar, of course, but the converse is not true. So, this condition is necessary bu not sufficient for collinearity.

Comment: When weshow calr multiple will it not show that they are parrallel and will not comment on their collinear

Comment: As I said ... a,b,c are collinear if and only if u and v are parallel.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that k,l,m are collinear if and only if u and v are parallel.